# Display the category name in wordpress loop only once

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to keep my "category name" in the loop, but display it only once for the first post? And not all the posts. I know i can keep it out of the loop, but just wondering if this is possible.

```
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order'   => 'ASC',
                    'cat' => 19

                    );

            $catg = new WP_Query($args);

            ?>

            <?php if($catg->have_posts()) : ?>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 lock">

            <?php while($catg->have_posts()) : $catg->the_post() ?>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 lock">

              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"> 
                    <?php
                    $category = get_the_category();
                    ?>
                    <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $category[1]->cat_name; ?></h2>                 
            </div>



                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 lock">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>" class="topico1-link-c">
                        <div class="topico3-col2-c cursos-margem-direita col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="padding-left: 0px;">
                            <div class="topico1-img col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 lock">
                                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)); ?>">
                                <div class="imagem-pelicula"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="topico1-title col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                                <h3 class="h3-low-c"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>                          
                </div>

            </div>

            <?php endwhile ?>

            <?php endif ?>

            </div>
```

Also is there a way to get the child category name? When i try this:

```
                    <?php
                    $category = get_the_category();
                    ?>
                    <h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo 
                    $category[1]->cat_name; ?></h2>
```

I get the right information, but if for some reason the parent name comes alphabetically in second, i get the parent name and not the child.

Thank you in advance.

Kind regards!

Comment: if you post current output and expected output, then it would be easy to related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an index that increases automatically with the loop, and an `if` condition only for the first iteration:

Before the loop:

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
```

Inside the loop:

```
<?php
  $category = get_the_category();
?>
<h2 style="text-transform: uppercase;">
<?php
  if($i == 1) { 
    echo $category[1]->cat_name; 
  }
  $i++;
?>
</h2>
```

`$i == 1` will only be right the first time (then the index is increase by `$i++`), so in all following loop cycles the category name output will be omitted.

Comment: Following your answer my posts get, i = 2, i = 3, i = 4, and so on, and all the posts get the title. If out of the loop i set <?php $i = null; ?>, my posts get i = 1, i = 2 and I = 3, and only  the first post doesn't get the title. I think we are near, but still a bit lost. Can you help? ;)

Comment: oops, sorry about that, that was wrong thinking - I changed it now to have the `echo` in the if condition, not the `get_the_category();` tag....

Comment: Yes, you are right! This worked :). Thanks. If possible can you tell me how can i get always the child category name, since "$category[1]->cat_name" only gets the child name when the parent is the first, but in some cases the parent category comes second, because i think wordpress sort categories alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

try this it is working for me

```
                        <?php   if( get_the_title() ){
                        $tit = get_the_title();
                        $tit = substr(get_the_title(), 0, 35);
                        echo $tit.'...';
                        }?>
```